# Cannot install TensorFlow 1.x

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow 1.14 for a package that I am trying to use. I tried:
`pip3 uninstall tensorflow`

Then I tried to install Tensorflow 1.14 using:
`pip3 install tensorflow==1.14`

and I get the following error
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14 (from versions: 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14`

I also tried making a new virtual env and tried the following commands but it didn't work. Is there any way to install Tensorflow 1?

Comment: have you tried pip install tensorflow

Comment: that would install the current TensorFlow version which is 2.x

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I've found on [discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/no-matching-distribution-found-for-tensorflow-1-15-2-from-deepspeech-training-0-7-3/61485/3):

`You just need to make sure you’re using Python 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7. TensorFlow 1.15 does not support Python 3.8`

Answer (score 8):

It works for me to install 1.x tensorflow with the following command:

```py
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: This solution only works for mac.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the final version of TensorFlow 1.15 using,

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

Make sure that you are using a python3 virtual environment and Python version is 3.6 or above. 

Or you may use Conda environment and install using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.15
```

Comment: Still gives the same error except for 1.15, when I say uninstall tensorflow I get WARNING: Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed. My environment has Python 3.8.3 but I have also tried Python 3.7.

Comment: Try installing in a new clean fresh environment or use Google Colab for time being, its works fine there.

Comment: So there isn't any way to install TensorFlow 1.x? Colab won't work for the work that I am doing.

Comment: The only option is to use a new environment because TensorFlow 1.15 works perfectly fine in my system.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what being said (i.e. the version), be sure that it is 64-bits version because Tensorflow is not working with Python 32 bits (or at least the recent versions).

You can check your version by typing `python` in the command line and check what appears.

For example, this is for 32 bits
[image: python 32bits]

and for 64bits
[image: python 64bits]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while installing tensorflow version 1.14.0. The best solution i tried is:
Note that your Python version is 3.7.8
Steps:

1. Open python 3.7.8 script folder **C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts** folder and type "**cmd**" in above bar, which opens it in the command prompt.
2. To install tensorflow-1.14.0 type : **pip install tensorflow==1.14.0**
3. To install keras-2.2.4 type : **pip install keras==2.2.4**

Answer (score 0):

From [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39768) on the Tensorflow Github titled *Tensorflow 1.x not available for python 3.8*:

---

**Saduf2019**: TensorFlow 1.x even 2.1 does not support Python 3.8

**mihaimaruseac**: We don't add new versions of Python for old releases. If you want to use TF 1.15, you have to use Python 3.7 or lower. If you want to use Python 3.8 you have to use TF 2.2 or newer.

---

Sounds like support for newer versions of Python > 3.7 won't be available for any tensorflow 1.x < 1.15.